# Should domain model ever get into invalid state? [Exceptions vs. imperative validation]

Tags: domain-driven-design

I've read a lot and I still can't make up my mind about which is the better approach with regard to Domain Validation in DDD.

We have 2 major ambitions:

**Ambition 1**
Model should never ever end up in an invalid state. Its state should be changed strictly through its methods which, in turn, would throw exceptions if passed invalid arguments.

What I like about this approach is that you end up with clean, guaranteed states possible.

What I don't like is that all model calling code ends up with explosion of exceptions handling which doesn't sound right.

**Ambition 2**
Abandon ambition 1, let models end up in invalid state but in the code that uses the model call model.IsValid() and if false do model.GetErrors() and go from there.

This approach kills a ton of exceptions but its not that nice that you have to check explicitly for errors.

I just can't make my mind yet. I hope someone might offer some convincing argument for any of approaches here to help me make my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your context and I think that there is a reasonable cause to use both patterns.  Sometimes a state that looks 'invalid' is actually valid in a given context, and the ability to determine the validity is a meaningful domain operation.

A pattern we've adopted in a recent system is to have two separate contexts:

1. input collector & validator
2. meaningful business function

In the first context, the data is populated onto the entity as submitted, and entity contains the business rules of determining validity - but the validity becomes a state of the entity.  This allows the API consumer to submit data, and retrieve the resource associated with the entity, including meaningful representations of valid or invalid statuses and reasons.

If the entity is valid, then a key business rule in this context is that it permits a state transition that causes (via a domain event) a command to be sent to the second context.

In the second context, invalid states are not permitted, and are enforced by throwing exceptions.

The value of this pattern is that in the first context, we collect data on the types of invalid data submitted by users and give the api consumer persistent access to the history of their operations including the records captured around what was invalid and why.

But in the second context, which contains more meaningful business logic, the business logic can be kept quite clean and clear because once the entity is successfully constructed, the code can assume a valid state.

Comment: i think this might be something very nice! so if i understand correctly, when model is just being set you allow invalid state but you indicate it within some IsValid() or GetErrors() or whatever. But when you try to perform any business/repository actions on the model then you throw exception related strictly to that method intention/context. Is that what you're saying?

Comment: Not quite - a context is not just an 'intention' - it is a 'bounded context' from DDD strategic patterns.  This means that the entity model in context 1 is a completely different class from the entity model in context 2, and usually, they will each have their own persistence layers and storage.  In our system, we use separate databases.

Comment: hm...then i must admit i dont quite understand. could you maybe please give some pseudo code example? (not sure why you've got downvote though as i have a gut feeling you are proposing something good)

Comment: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html is good overview of the bounded context from a modelling perspective. From an implementation perspective it helps to consider the microservices architectural approach, where each bounded context is embodied in a separate microservice - see http://blog.xebia.com/microservices-architecture-principle-3-small-bounded-contexts-over-one-comprehensive-model/.  The key point of my answer, though, is that Ambitions 1 & 2 are not one-size-fits-all.  Sometimes the requirements of a given context will suggest Ambition 1, sometimes it will be Ambition 2.

Comment: i am familiar with bounded contexts but the point where i got confused is that seems at one point of time you have switched to crossing bounded context boundaries and when doing so we can hardly speak about same entity anymore. and what i am interested about is the same entity behavior. or, to speak in this language: validation of one model within one bounded context: returning error collections or throwing exceptions. so, from link example you gave it would be: how to implement validation for Pipeline model within Sales context? hope that makes sense.

Comment: We can speak about the same _conceptual_ entity in different contexts - just modelled differently - i.e. modelled appropriately for the purpose of the context.  In our case it is an invoice - in the submission context the invoice entity class just has methods for validation.  In the processing context it has calculation methods & authorization state management, and throws exceptions if invalid.  The same _conceptual_ entity can move through multiple contexts on it's lifecycle journey - e.g. consider an Order in an e-commerce context vs a fulfillment context.  Same Order, different models.

Comment: ok, then in terms of your case i would like to ask how do you implement invoice validation within boundaries of submission context alone? so validation methods it has - how are they implemented? do they throw exceptions or just add to some Errors[] collection on the model that code using the model can inspect?

Comment: Yes - in the submission context, we follow a pattern more like your ambition 2.  Validation methods return results of particular validation checks, and a ValidationErrors collection returns a list of all validation errors.

Comment: Yes, i think you have a very good point with your approach. That feels like a nice balance between 2 approaches. I will leave question opened for a bit more for more potential answers but yours is a candidate for being marked as answer for now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

DDD advocates for the Ambition 1, so an entity or value object can never be in an invalid state. What you don't like about this is that you have to handle the exceptions. There is many ways of handling exceptions properly. You can either let the exception propagate and catch it in a higher level or create your main Domain exceptions so it can be easier to handle. But as a general rule if something went wrong (exception) it should be taken care of.

For the "Ambition 2" I don't think it is a good idea since everywhere you will have to deal with an object you need first to check if it is valid or not cause you can never guarantee that. And I this can easily become much more complicated than catching exceptions. Think about aggregates you need to make sure every object in the aggregate is valid.

Comment: second part of your answer is a very good point actually! using object on many places is a very good argument for exceptions! // for first part, some would argue that if you could envision it going wrong then its not exception. not saying its right, just pointing out how hard it is to find consensus on these kind of things.

Comment: There is a distinction between exceptions - something's not going according to the happy path - and failures - something's gone wrong and hasn't been dealt with (possibly because it hasn't been envisioned to ever happen). IMHO it's ok to model unusual but predicted circumstances as exceptions. I didn't even know there wasn't a consensus on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

For *data validation*, you almost always want to have a very clear boundary between "here's a representation of something, but I don't know if its any good", and "here's a representation of something that satisfies all of the constraints for use".

Once a piece of immutable data has been checked, it should be tagged so that all of the consumers know that it is good.  The usual mechanism for tagging is to rely on the type system.  `Money.amount` is represented in memory as an immutable integer, but we also have the guarantee that it is non negative (or whatever).

An alternative to having a factory return a object that you have to check for validity, is to have it return an object that captures the fact that the object may not have been valid.

```
Try<Money> money = MoneyTree.showMeTheMoney(-7)
```

`money`, in this example, is either going to be a `Success<Money>`, if the MoneyTree was able to do something useful with `-7`, or it's going to be a `Failure`.

[In 2014, Maurício Linhares](https://mauricio.github.io/2014/02/17/scala-either-try-and-the-m-word.html) wrote a summary of the idea.  Google will lead you to others.

The tactical patterns in the Blue Book were drawn from what were understood to be best practices in Java circa 2003.  In particular, Evans explicitly calls out the fact that the coding patterns should allows the developers to work with the domain, rather than the plumbing.  Exceptions *tend* to be a better choice for that so that the domain semantics aren't lost behind a bunch of error handling.

For domain logic, on the other hand, exceptions are a poor choice; if the business problem that you are modeling has multiple paths; then the code structure should make those paths explicit -- using exceptions to model control flow is usually a bad idea, and domain driven design does not include any constraints that would require them.

Comment: Thank you for your very good answer! I agree that exceptions used for control flow are a poor choice. They are probably a good option when operation cannot be performed for some reason and that reason has to be solved before going on. Have to check that read you propose. thanks!